# Escape from server side form validation

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib, xpages-ssjs

In my app I have chosen to rely on server side validation only.
I use a toolbar (xe:toolbar) action to save my document, and I have this code in the 'OnItemClick' event:

```
var toolbarAction = context.getSubmittedValue();

if (toolbarAction == "save"){
    docPrognosis.save();
    context.redirectToPage("prognosisview.xsp");
} else if (toolbarAction == "edit") {
    var url = view.getPageName() + "?action=editDocument&documentId=" + param.get("documentId");
    context.redirectToPage(url);
} else if (toolbarAction == "abort"){
    context.redirectToPage("prognosisview.xsp");
} else {
   "";
}
```

When I press the abort action I want to navigate a different page. Instead the form validation kicks in and tells me that I need to complete all the required fields.

How do I get around this?

Comment: @Knut: I think that this here is slightly different as <xe:toolbar> has just one common EventHandler. So bypassing validation might not be an option here

Comment: @Lothar: I see, I deleted comment and close flag and gave +1 for Ove's answer :)

Answer (score 1):

When using the xe:toolbar you have the option to run CSJS directly from the treenodes or SSJS indirectly using the 'submitvalue' from your treenodes utilizing the onItemClick event.

My bad was that I submitted the abort action to the server instead of directly navigating away from the page in my basicLeafNode entry.

(it's almost like i feel like apologizing...)